# There is any way from inside an App to tell iOS to connect to a particular Network?

Tags: ios

I am trying to build an iOS App that chooses a local WiFi network (created with raspberry pi on the server side), connects to it to transfer some data (camera photos), and then in the end of transmission, I will need to close that connection and reconnect to some other network with internet access (to send the photos).

I want to do all this steps without forcing the user to go Settings/Wi-Fi and manually choosing each network every times this operation is required.

I have search Apple official documentation and found nothing about this, any ideas?

Comment: Short answer: no, it's impossible

Comment: Thanks. It's sad, so I will have to develop it in another OS in order to accomplish this task.

Comment: but you can get mac address of router and check that you connected to right network and ask user to chose another network if necessary